# How can I set up SSH reverse to access a lan webserver behind a firewall?

Tags: ssh, reverse

i want to make reverse ssh like this

```
webserver -- my office pc -- FIREWALL -- MY VPS -- my home pc

10.5.1.197:80 - webserver
10.5.1.29 - my office pc
163.111.222.333 - MY VPS

ssh -R 163.111.222.333:8080:10.5.1.197:80 autossh@163.111.222.333
```

it not working, anyone here can help me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Alas, this question is not about programming, so it's off-topic for SO and would be better addressed on one of the other StackExchange sites. In fact, it has already been asked, so you might want to just close this question and head over to [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46235/13377) for the guidance you're looking for.

Comment: sorry wrong place